# OpenCV/QThread segfault

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a biometric login project, where face recognition is a part of. We are using OpenCV 2.4.13. We have a Qt GUI app which spawns a thread and passes it a picture to verify like this:

```
void MainWindow::on_button_test_auth_clicked()
{
    statusLabel->setText("Authenticating...");
    statusLabel->repaint();

    Mat* takenImage = cam->takePicture();

    AuthThread *authThread = new AuthThread();
    connect(authThread, SIGNAL(resultReady(const QString&)), this, SLOT(setLabelText(const QString&)));
    connect(authThread, &AuthThread::finished, authThread, &QObject::deleteLater);

    authThread->passTakenImage(*takenImage);
    authThread->start();   

    delete takenImage;
}
```

AuthThread looks like:

```
class AuthThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    void run() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createLBPHFaceRecognizer(4,8,8,8);

        model->load(Config::getModelFile().toStdString());

        int label = -1;
        double distance = 0.0;

        model->predict(takenImage, label, distance);

        QString labelString;
        QTextStream labelStream(&labelString);

        double threshold = Config::getThreshold();

        if(distance < threshold) {
            labelStream << "Authenticated as " << label << "! " << QString::number((threshold - distance), 'f', 2) << " under threshold.";
        } else {
            labelStream << "Not authenticated! " << QString::number((distance - threshold), 'f', 2) << "over threshold.";
        }

        emit resultReady(labelString);
    }

public:
    void passTakenImage(Mat& img) {
        takenImage = img;
    }

private:
    Mat takenImage;
signals:
    void resultReady(const QString &s);
};
```

This all works fine on the first time `on_button_test_auth_clicked()` gets called, but the second time it segfaults on `model->predict(takenImage, label, distance);`

I've tried running valgrind to see what exactly is going wrong, but I'm fairly new to c++ so I can't make much sense of the output, which is:

```
==6732== Thread 12 AuthThread:
==6732== Invalid read of size 8
==6732==    at 0x8C94262: ??? (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==6732==    by 0x8C9432A: ??? (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==6732==    by 0x8C95E27: ??? (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==6732==    by 0x8C94C21: ??? (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==6732==    by 0x8C8F50F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==6732==    by 0x8C8D724: tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==6732==    by 0x530D7DA: tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, cv::calcHist1D_Invoker<float>, tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, cv::calcHist1D_Invoker<float> const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) (in /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.13)
==6732==    by 0x531378A: cv::calcHist(cv::Mat const*, int, int const*, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int const*, float const**, bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.13)
==6732==    by 0x5DABFA5: ??? (in /usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.13)
==6732==    by 0x5DB5899: ??? (in /usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.13)
==6732==    by 0x5DB64DD: cv::LBPH::predict(cv::_InputArray const&, int&, double&) const (in /usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.13)
==6732==    by 0x428940: AuthThread::run() (auththread.h:28)
==6732==  Address 0xfffffffffffffff7 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6732== 
==6732== 
==6732== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==6732==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7
==6732==    at 0x8C94262: ??? (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==6732==    by 0x8C9432A: ??? (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==6732==    by 0x8C95E27: ??? (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==6732==    by 0x8C94C21: ??? (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==6732==    by 0x8C8F50F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==6732==    by 0x8C8D724: tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::allocate(unsigned long) const (in /usr/lib/libtbb.so.2)
==6732==    by 0x530D7DA: tbb::interface9::internal::start_for<tbb::blocked_range<int>, cv::calcHist1D_Invoker<float>, tbb::auto_partitioner const>::run(tbb::blocked_range<int> const&, cv::calcHist1D_Invoker<float> const&, tbb::auto_partitioner const&) (in /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.13)
==6732==    by 0x531378A: cv::calcHist(cv::Mat const*, int, int const*, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int const*, float const**, bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.13)
==6732==    by 0x5DABFA5: ??? (in /usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.13)
==6732==    by 0x5DB5899: ??? (in /usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.13)
==6732==    by 0x5DB64DD: cv::LBPH::predict(cv::_InputArray const&, int&, double&) const (in /usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.13)
==6732==    by 0x428940: AuthThread::run() (auththread.h:28)
==6732==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6732==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6732==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==6732==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6732==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
```

This seems to indicate something is going wrong in libtbb.so, thread building blocks, which I assume is what is powering QThread.

Strange thing is, when I move the AuthThread code to `on_button_test_auth_clicked()` it works fine no matter how many times it gets called. Maybe something from the old thread sticks around and messes things up the second time?

The opencv Ptr, which works like a shared_ptr, should take care of cleaning up the model after it goes out of scope (explicitly releasing it does not help). All other things are stack allocated so they should not cause any memory issues as far as I know.

Another thing I tried was cloning the image Mat, in case it accidentally got deleted somehow before it was needed. That did not help either.

To add to the fun, this exact code runs fine on the computers of the guys I'm working with. Any help/tips would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is more general, but it is good practice to always ask for a null pointer before dereferencing. I.e.: put a `if(model)` anywhere before you try to derefence. E.g.: `model->predict(takenImage, label, distance);`. This should avoid the segfault you are experiencing. Hope this helps while debugging.

Comment: didnt read your code, did you secure your critical sections with mutex or atomic operations? Maybe some thread is reading a variable, while another thread is writing it => big trouble

Comment: @Micka I did not write this code, but I'll check if that is the case. It seems all variables are local to the thread itself except maybe takenImage, but I think that one is copied anyways. I think the strangest thing is the fact that this code works fine all the time on the other two machines that run it.

Comment: @tobilocker Thanks! I will keep that in mind. model is not a nullpointer when the crash happens according to my debugger, but it's nice to know what is considered good practice.

Comment: don't use: delete takenImage; use a smart pointer for Mat* takenImage

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a reference to a null object:

```
void passTakenImage(Mat& img) {
```

Before AuthThread will start working, the object is deleted:

```
delete takenImage;
```

So, pass by value, not by reference:

```
void passTakenImage(Mat img) {
```

Now, AuthThread will work on a copy of img that is alive as long as AuthThread is alive.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken an opencv Mat contains a pointer to it's data along with a reference count, so as soon as the image gets passed to the thread the Mat itself gets copied as it is assigned to the class field takenImage. The old Mat then indeed gets deleted, but as there is now another Mat pointing to the same data, that data does not get deleted. I tried explicitly cloning the Mat, using a smart pointer, and passing by value, none of which worked. The strange thing is, the segfault only happens the second time the thread is instantiated. Because valgrind pointed me to libtbb.so...

Comment: ... I tried replacing it with another version. I am running arch myself so I replaced it with a version I copied from my ubuntu VM, and guess what. It runs flawlessly. Now I'm not nearly experienced enough to know for certain this is a bug in libtbb or anything (which seems unlikely, as I think it is made by intel?) or  it might be a bug in the way opencv handles it's threads. Maybe you or anyone else can point me in the right direction? I'd love to get to the bottom of this.